# Update lists elements programmatically looping through the lists names

Tags: r, non-standard-evaluation

I need to update lists elements programmatically looping through the lists names in R.

Is there a way to do that using some sort of Non-Standard Evaluation or another method?

## Pseudo-code of a minimum example:

```r
  x = list(a=1)
  y = list(a=3)
  
  for(i in c("x", "y")){
    
    i[["a"]] <- 10
  }
```

## Expected results:

```r
  x[["a"]] == 10
  y[["a"]] == 10
```

### Edit: I found this way to update the values directly without making a copy of the lists via `get(i)`:

```r
x = list(a=1)
y = list(a=3)

.env = pryr::where("x")

for(i in c("x", "y")){
    
  .env [[ i ]] [[ "a" ]] <- 10
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"x"`, `"y"` are strings, we need to `get` the value as well as `assign`

```
for(i in c("x", "y")) {
    tmp <- get(i)
    tmp[["a"]] <- 10
    assign(i, tmp)
}
```

-checking

```
> x
$a
[1] 10

> y
$a
[1] 10
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention that I do not want to copy the list via `get(i)` since the list can have a very large size. I will edit my question to include a solution I come up that can update the lists elements directly.

Comment: @GitHunter0 you can also use base R i.e.`.GlobalEnv[[i]][["a"]] <- 10`

Comment: Yes, but since I'm using Shiny, I have to get the specific environment.

Comment: @GitHunter0 You could define the objects in `global.R` and then source it if it is in shiny.

Comment: @GitHunter0 if it is reactive objects, you can also check [here](https://github.com/rjake/shinyobjects)